# How to get the path of Qweb report in Odoo 11?

Tags: path, odoo, qweb

I'm on a Qweb Report, I have done :

```
<div style="background:url('unknown_path') ...>
```

And I want to set the path of an image stored on my server. So I need to know here I am, to set a relative path.

My report is written in */usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons_adquat/adquat_distribinox_report/report_view.xml* but I don't know if the path in the background:url will be from there.

Is it a way to output the path in the report, or to put a breakpoint ? 
In Qweb I tried `<t t-debug />`, `<t t-debug="">` and `<t t-debug="debug">` but it doesn't work.

Other question : can I set an absolute path on the server (like /home/user/myimage.jpg) or it has to be in the odoo directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Odoo paths are relative to the `addons` directory where your module lives. From your question I infer that your module is called `adquat_distribinox_report` so, following the Odoo Guidelines (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/guidelines.html#module-structure), you should put your background file in

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons_adquat/adquat_distribinox_report/static/img/background.png`

and call it using:

```
<div style="background-image:url('/adquat_distribinox_report/static/img/background.png') ...>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works !
I have added `addons_adquat/` to the addons_path, so I suppose it's the same thing (all paths are relative to addons/ or addons_adquat/)